# Mass downloading raster tiles using QGIS

Tags: qgis, tiles, download

I want to mass download georectified sat image tiles (XYZ tiles) and save them locally.

I could setup QGIS so I can see google sat images.
So for example, I want all tiles of Los Angeles in a geo resolution of 50x50 m (and let the pixel resolution be whatever it will be then) and 200 x 200 tiles of that.

How I am going to approach this problem?

Comment: XYZ Tiles, google sat server: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}

Comment: I dont intent to use it for any commercial apps

Comment: If you dont find any other way you can use print composer and atlas

Comment: Ok thanks, I take a look into it

Comment: Might be easier to write a script in python or some other language. If you know the zoom level and the range of x and y it would be a series of http requests in a nested loop.

Comment: I do know this parameters, but I dont know the python libs necessary for capturing a http request

Comment: A download manager like https://jdownloader.org/ could do the job for you